# List item becomes unclickable if contains a RatingBar?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have used **custom** listview and **custom** rating bar.

If *I add that custom `RatingBar` as child to the `List item`*, **the List Item becomes unclickable**.

If *i remove that Ratingbar view then it becomes clickable* .

I used custom rating bar. here is the [link](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-custom-ratingbar-example.html).

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: add `android:focusable="false"` in rating bar in xml file

Comment: @SamirMangroliya Sorry Samir Not working

Comment: add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in row & main xml file, in main layout,hope it will work.

Comment: Do you want your rating bar stars to rate? or static rates?

Comment: @LalitPoptani Show static rates .

Comment: @ChiragRaval i have customized listview with rating bar and its works without `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: I think this link will help you.... [link](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android7dvancedListView.php) Thanks....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want your rating bar to perform rating you can add

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to view of your `row.xml`

If you want a static rating bar holding its rate you can give [setIsIndicator(boolean isIndicator)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setIsIndicator%28boolean%29)

```
ratingbar.setIsIndicator(true);
```

in your Adapter class.

Comment: `setIsIndicator` is also available in XML with `android:isIndicator="true"`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I'm  able to do it finally.
In adapter class put fallowing

RatingBar ratingBar=(RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarSummaryChild);

ratingBar.setFocusable(false);

return view;

Comment: For some reason, this was the only solution that worked for me.  Setting this in xml as others answered did not!

Answer (score 1):

set android:focusable="false" for rating bar

Answer (score 0):

Set RatingBar propertiesa
Focusable = false;
Clickable = false;