# How to enable onListItemClick for a ListActivity where list item has a ratingBar

Tags: android, listactivity, ratingbar

I am having a listActivity in my application in which each of the list items has some text view and icons. Along with that I have an ImageView for which I have implemented onClicklistener and also a ratingBar which I need to just display the rating for that listItem.

Now my problem is after implementing all this I am not able to click on the listItem as a whole. When digging the internet I found that we can't use any buttons in the listView because they take control of the click events on listItems. But I haven't used any Buttons. I am sure the clickable Image view is not causing any issues. The only possible culprit here is the RatingBar. So I need to set some attributes to the rating bar so that it doesn't take control over the click events of the whole listItem.

I've tried different combinations of disabling the following attributes, but still no luck

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:longclickable="false"
```

Please tell me if I am missing out on something or there is any other way by which we can make the rating bar non-clickable/non-editable.

P.S. I am new to android development and This is my first question here on stackoverflow so please pardon me if I have made any mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List item becomes unclickable if contains a RatingBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031763/list-item-becomes-unclickable-if-contains-a-ratingbar)

Comment: @LalitPoptani Thanks for the link. I already tried most of the things mentioned there. Need to check the `android:isIndicator="false"` attribute for the ratingBar. I hope that will solve my problem. Thanks once again.

Comment: Setting the attribute `android:isIndicator="false"` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try below property within row file main layout.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"